# display contents of manytomany and foreignjey fields in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to Django and I'ma building a basic blog application.
I cant show manytomany field (in tags) and a foreignkey field (comments) in my details page.

models.py

```
class BlogContent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class TagName(models.Model):
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(BlogContent, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Comment(models.Model):
    comt_text = models.TextField()
    comments = models.ForeignKey(BlogContent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_published = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def details(request, blogcontent_id):
    data_blog = get_object_or_404(BlogContent, pk=blogcontent_id)
    data_tag = get_object_or_404(TagName, pk=blogcontent_id)
    data_comment = Comment.objects.select_related()

    return render(request, 'details.html',
              {'data_blog': data_blog, 'data_tag':data_tag, 'data_comment':data_comment})
```

details.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body_base %}
 <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src={{ data_blog.image.url }} alt="Card image cap">
        <h2 class="blog-post-title">{{ data_blog.title }}</h2>
        <p class="blog-post-meta">{{ data_blog.date_published }} {{ data_blog.author }}</p>

        <p>{{ data_blog.content }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

how do i show foreignkey and manaytomany fieds after this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBH this is much easier if you use class based views.

The view would simply be:

```
class BlogContentDetail (DetailView):
    model = BlogContent
```

The url call would be `url(r'^blog-detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$, BlogContentDetail.as_view(), name="blog_detail")`

Your html file should be called `blogcontent_detail.html` and held within the app subfolder in the templates folder

The template would then be:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body_base %}
 <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src={{ object.image.url }} alt="Card image cap">
        <h2 class="blog-post-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
        <p class="blog-post-meta">{{ object.date_published }} {{ object.author }}</p>

        <p>{{ object.content }}</p>
       {% for tag in object.tags_set.all %}{{ tag }}{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the ManyToMany Field in this way 
 
`{% for tags in  data_tag.tag.all %}
<p > {{tags}} </ p>
{% endfor %}`

For foreign key

`{{data_comment.comments}}`

Comment: not working. i get this error. "'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable"

Comment: Try data_tag.tag.all